# No bootable devices found. UEFI boot and SUSE 11 SP3

Tags: boot, uefi, bootloader, opensuse, suse

I have a SUSE 11 SP3 insallation that have been used on Dell Optiplex XE and Dell Optiplex XE2 successfull.

The problem occur now when I try on a Dell Optiplex XE3. It is not possible to boot legacy anymore. Not possible to start SUSE installation dvd from the internal DVD.

I have tried to install from an USB-connected-external-DVD and it works. BUT!!! when I reboot the computer without having the external-DVD connected it wont boot. just come to black screen with the text "No bootable devicecs found"

Does anyone have an idea what I can do to make it work? and why it is possible to boot when the external-DVD is connected?

Comment: More than likely your UEFI `BOOTXXXX` variables are not correctly set or are undefined.

Comment: What do you mean with UEFI BOOTXXXX?

Comment: UEFI NVRAM boot variables are named `BOOT0001`, `BOOT0002` and so on.

Comment: Is it possible to change UEFI boot variabels?